# reference as class member variable without initialization

Tags: c++, reference

Is there a way to use a reference as a member variable without initialising it in the constructor?
My problem is that I don't have the reference at hand when constructing the object.

Comment: Show what you would like to do. You may not need to perform all initialization inside the constructor, something can be done lazy when you'll need it.

Comment: Can you construct the object after you have the reference to hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`> Is there a way to use a reference as a member variable without initialising it in the constructor?`

No, references must be initialized in constructor initializer list

`> My problem is that I don't have the reference at hand when constructing the object.`

I guess what you meant is you don't have an object to refer to. In that case you have to go for a pointer and initialize it to NULL. Then later when you have the object make the pointer point to that. A reference cannot be used in this case as you cannot initialize reference to NULL

Answer (score 4):

No. References must be initialized on creation and cannot be modified thereafter. The standard states that

> A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or
>   function.

If you don't have the target object at hand on construction, switch to using a pointer instead of a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Once a reference is initialized, it will, for the time of his life, point to the same entity. Any attempt to "reseat" it results in undefined behaviour.

So short answer: If you can't initialize, you can't use it.